# Give an example of $h$ and $h_n$ where h is not continuous at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, sequence-of-function

All of the following have to hold for the function and the sequence that are given as an example:

1) $h(x)=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}h_n(x)$

2) $\{h_n(x)\}$ is a sequence of decreasing non-negative functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

3) h(x) cannot be continuous at $0$.

Any tip or hints at building this example will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just make $h_n(x) = h(x)$ for all $n$.

Comment: you should put the criterion that $h(x)$ is not continuous at $0$ in the body of the question too; does $h_n(x)$ have to be continuous?  consider exponential functions with a negative sign in the exponent

Comment: Thank you, will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $h_n(x)=h(x)=e^{-x}+1$ for $x <0$, $h_n(x)=h(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x \geq 0$.